# Extract financial fundamental from Yahoo finance with excel

Tags: excel, vba, yahoo-finance

Yahoo changed his structure for the financials (fundamental) report.
In the past (last month) at the page https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL&guccounter=1 I could download the information regarding the financial Income Statement or Balance Sheet or Cash Flow in VBA Excel as a table.
Now they have updated the "new" version that appears as a table but I cannot extract it con VBA Excel.
There someone that can help me?
If you need I can post the code in VBA regarding the old version, that can download all the tables in the HTML page.

To better explain I need the information in the yellow box.
[image]
You can see that it appears as a table, but if you look inside in the HTML code there is not the normal tag regarding tables.
I identify that the starting "table" has this tag `<div class="D(tbrg)"` but I don't know how to proceed to extract data.
The same "table" is in the Balance Sheet and Cash Flow selection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I do not extract information from Yahoo but I have and do extract information from other websites and electronic files.  The authors of such data regularly change the format (an extra column here or a rearrangement there).  Perhaps they think they are improving it or perhaps they wish to discourage its use in this way.  Either way, there is no point starting this type of extraction unless you are able to update your routines quickly after each format change.  If someone here helped you update your routine, it would only delay the need for you to be able do it yourself.

Comment: dear EliteRaceElephant

Comment: Dear EliteRaceElephant,
I tried to build up a new script, but the problem is that I don't know HTML well, so I cannot found the correct way to extract them

Comment: if you have Excel 2010+, you may be able to obtain the information by using `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform`

Comment: We can help you but please include your current attempt with the page shown and explain where code is failing and indicate the required output data and its format.

Comment: Dear QHarr I update my request with the part that I need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most modern webpages are designed to display attractively on both a PC and a smartphone despite their very different dimensions. Those I have examined, build the components of the display using fairly standard HTML then use device dependent, complex CCS to position those components. You cannot work down the displayed page and the HTML and expect to find some simple match between them. Each component will be blocked with divs, named with a class, so the CCS can position the components as appropriate for the device. You need to find the components which may not be what you expect. ...

Comment: ... My guess is you will have to extract the contents of each component separately and then merge them as the CCS does for a PC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub Yahoo_BS()

Dim xmlHttp As Object
Dim TR_col As Object, Tr As Object
Dim TD_col As Object, Td As Object
Dim row As Long, col As Long

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    myURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBUX/balance-sheet?p=SBUX"
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlHttp.send

    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText

    Dim tbl As Object
    Set tbl = html.getElementById("Pos(r)")


    row = 1
    col = 1

    Set TR_col = html.getElementsByTagName("TR")
    For Each Tr In TR_col
        Set TD_col = Tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")
        For Each Td In TD_col
            Cells(row, col) = Td.innerText
            col = col + 1
        Next
        col = 1
        row = row + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Keep in mind that this is just one way to do it.  I'm sure there are several means to the same end.  Also, think about looping through an array of ticker symbols.  You can add new sheets for each ticker and import the relevant data for each symbol that you query for.

Please click the check to say the answer is useful if this solution helps you.

Comment: I tried your Macro but I received an error: 
run-time error '5' "Invalid procedure call or argument" 
the problem is in the line 4 ".CommandType = 0".

Comment: You can comment out that line and run it once more.  You have to figure it our yourself, or wait until I get back to the US.  Again, I'm in Spain, and everything here is translated into Spanish automatically.  Weird, but true.  When I get back to the US, on Saturday, I can see what's really going on.  Or, try to resolve the issue yourself.  Learning is fun.  It can be frustrating too.  Nevertheless, the benefits outweigh the costs.

Comment: Ciao asher, thx for your reply. Don't worry, I will try and I want to have your feedback when you are in US next week. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Ciao Asher. This weekend I tried to solve the problem. I commented the line .commantype = 0 but the macro did not extract nothing. So I tried to learn the function QueryTables.Add but it has been not very clear for me. So can you give me an update, please?

Comment: Ciao.  I am back home now and I can actually see what is going on at this point.  I just updated my original answer.  Use that script.  You should have what you need now.  This works for me; it should work for you.  Feel free to customize the code, of course, to do exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Ciao Asher. I thank you for helping. I copied and pasted your update, but when I run it, I received nothing. The sheet is without data. I think that I'm wrong about something, but I don't have ideas where. I'm sorry about it.

Comment: That was very weird.  I could swear the code from my last post initially worked, but when I just re-tried it, it did not work.  I changed the code and re-posted.  Try it again please.

Comment: Ciao Asher. thanks a lot for your help. I have already a script the same as you posted, that download the "tables" in the web site. But I need (see my post) a portion that appears as a  "table" but it is not downloaded as a table.