# How to pull financial statements from Yahoo Finance (2019 URL) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I copied the code from this link [Extract financial fundamental from Yahoo finance with excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58410896/extract-financial-fundamental-from-yahoo-finance-with-excel#)

The code from ASH works to pull balance sheet data; however, when I change the ticker (like MSFT), it begins pulling in the wrong data.

1. Why is it pulling in different data points than when I switch the ticker in the URL Link?
2. How can I go about correcting it?

   ```
   Sub Yahoo_BS()

   Dim xmlHttp As Object
   Dim TR_col As Object, Tr As Object
   Dim TD_col As Object, Td As Object
   Dim row As Long, col As Long

   Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
   myURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBUX/balance-sheet?p=SBUX"
   xmlHttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
   xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
   xmlHttp.send

   Dim html As Object
   Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
   html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText

   Dim tbl As Object
   Set tbl = html.getElementById("Pos(r)")


   row = 1
   col = 1

   Set TR_col = html.getElementsByTagName("TR")
   For Each Tr In TR_col
       Set TD_col = Tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")
       For Each Td In TD_col
           Cells(row, col) = Td.innerText
           col = col + 1
       Next
       col = 1
       row = row + 1
   Next

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/sbux/financials gives me different data than https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/fb/financials
maybe you try to change the parameter at the end? i think that one is not relevant

Comment: which parameter are you referencing?

Comment: parameter  ?p=SBUX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code works just fine for MSFT in so far as it works the same way for that ticker as it does for SBUX. The code you linked to is for retrieving **balance sheet** info for a given ticker.

`https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBUX/balance-sheet?p=SBUX`

or

`https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/balance-sheet?p=MSFT`

This does not guarantee you can *'lift and shift'* this code for use with any of the other tabs e.g. income statement which has the following construction:

`https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/financials?p=MSFT`

You will need to inspect the html of these tabs and see how it differs. There are already existing answers on StackOverflow covering how to obtain the data as shown in the other tabs (and by the different time periods e.g. Quarter).

---

VBA translation of [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58337027/6241235). In VBA it would benefit from re-factoring:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutFinancialInfo()
    Dim http As Object, s As String

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/financials?p=MSFT", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send
        s = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, html2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, re As Object, matches As Object
    
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set html2 = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    html.body.innerHTML = s
    
    Dim headers(), rows As Object
    
    headers = Array("Breakdown", "TTM")
    Set rows = html.querySelectorAll(".fi-row")
    
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"
        Set matches = .Execute(s)
    End With
    
    Dim results(), match As Object, r As Long, c As Long, startHeaderCount As Long
    startHeaderCount = UBound(headers)
    ReDim Preserve headers(0 To matches.Count + startHeaderCount)

    c = 1
    For Each match In matches
        headers(startHeaderCount + c) = match
        c = c + 1
    Next
    
    Dim row As Object
    ReDim results(1 To rows.Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
 
    For r = 0 To rows.Length - 1
        html2.body.innerHTML = rows.Item(r).outerHTML
        Set row = html2.querySelectorAll("[title],[data-test=fin-col]")
        
        For c = 0 To row.Length - 1
            results(r + 1, c + 1) = row.Item(c).innerText
        Next c
    Next
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Project references:**

VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: is this the kind of output you were after? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58337027/6241235

Comment: Yes, just need to figure out how to do it in VBA

Comment: I’ll write it in vba but I think it may already exist as an answer in vba on stack overflow. Have you had a look for the financial statements code?

Comment: I have found some older examples from Yahoo. They've recently changed site and a lot of the older code no longer works.

Comment: translation added.

Comment: Thank you. I am a VBA beginner, any idea why I'm getting a compile error from this line? Public Sub WriteOutFinancialInfo()

Comment: you need to go VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library  https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/calling-vba-in-add-ins-from-vba-modules